# Custom TOC with custom elements

Tags: table-of-contents

I've been looking to so many posts about TOC in Latex but couldn't find anything similar to my issue. I want to generate a table of contents but not based on the classical `\chapter` & `\section`. I have created some custom ones to adapt to my display. Let's call them `\customChapter` & `\customSection`.

How could I tell the my Latex to use them to automatically create a TOC ?

Regards,

Comment: Have you looked up which options the tocloft package provides for? This https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/601137/chapter-numbers-followed-by-a-dot-in-table-of-contents-toc-but-not-in-heading/601330#601330 provides for a personalized example.

Comment: Please provide an MWE (from `documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) showing what you have tried and that we can compile. In particular your definitions and usage of `\customChapter` and `\customSection`. How do you want them to be printed in the ToC?